# Why don't pictures display in my slider?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, slider

```
<div class="panel">
<?php $homethumb = get_post_meta($post->ID,'homethumb', true);?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" > <img src="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-content/uploads/<? echo strtolower($homethumb); ?>.jpg" width="200" height="120" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"/> </a>
</div>
```

Comment: We don't know what your PHP script is doing, please view the source code in your browser and paste that instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't using short open tags, then it would not work, because your echo statement uses a `<?` (rather than a `<?php`) tag.

The following fixes the problem:

```
<div class="panel">
<?php $homethumb = get_post_meta($post->ID,'homethumb', true);?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" > <img src="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-content/uploads/<?php echo strtolower($homethumb); ?>.jpg" width="200" height="120" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"/> </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure the image you linked to in your HTML actually exists?